# Floating CSS is starting to look like a puzzle

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm writing a basic site for school and all the objects are floating all over the place. It's frustrating and I'm tired. No It's not due tonight. However, I'd like a few pointers to send me on my way. Should I delete my CSS code and start over making sure I double check everything, or do I have my margins all wrong?

**Screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CrjK.png

**XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">    

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sitestyle.css"/> 
</head>

<body id="home"> 

<div id="site"> 

<ul id ="nav_bar"> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="nutrition.html">Nutrition</a></li> 
    <li><a href="grooming.html">Grooming</a></li> 
    <li><a href="about.html">About</li> 
</ul> 

<div id="header">  
    <h1> Cat Site!</h1> 
    <h2>By: XXX XXX</h2>   
</div>

<address class="info">
<a href='mailto:&#116;&#109;&#107;&#114;&#97;&#117;&#115;&#53;&#64;&#99;&#99;&#46;&#117;&#109;&#66;&#666;&#666;&#666;&#666;&#666;&#666;&#46;&#666;&#66;'>&#69;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108</a></br>
Developed with: Firefox 16.0.2.  
</address>  


</div> 
<!-- End of info and header objects-->

<div id="col1"> 

    <img src="kitty.png" </> 
    Source: Shitty_Watercolour <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/12zcnm/excuse_my_derp_face_but_i_think_i_just_accidently/c6zh53e"</a> 


</div>
<!--End of Col1-->

<div id="col2">  

<h2>Welcome!</h2> 

<h3 class ="subheading">What is this Cat site about?</h3> 
<p class = "sitetext"> Everyone loves cats. Yes, even you! This website should help you educate yourself about our feline friends briefly. 
That is to say, you won't waste a lot of unnecessary time here.</p> 

<!--End of col2 div-->
</div> 

<div style="text-align:center;color:black">     
     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Last update: " + document.lastModified); 
     </script>      
 </div> 

<!--End of site-->
</div> 


</body> 
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#header { 
color: black;  
float: center;

}

ul#nav_bar {  
list-style-type: none;  
margin: 0;  
margin-left:0px;
font-size: 125%; 
color: pink; 
width: 25%; 
float: justified;
} 

#nav_bar li {   
float: left; 
}

#nav_bar a { 
display: block; background: pink; 
color: white; 
padding: 4px 6px; 
border: 1px solid; 
text-decoration: none; 
}

div#col2 { 
width: 50%; 
float: right; 
padding-left: 2.5%;
padding-right: 2.5%; 
background: grey; 
} 

#col1 { 
float: left; 
clear: left; 
font-size: 75%; 
text-align: center; 
margin: 1em 0 1.5em 1.5em; 
display: block; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is give your footer (where you put the javascript for the last modified date) the style "clear: both;". This bit of styling prevents the element from being mixed inline with the floated elements, moving it to the position directly below them. That should fix most of the layout problems.

I also noticed a few things in your code, that bear mentioning:

- in html, there can't be spaces in attributes, i.e.: `class="foo"`, not `class = "foo"`
- in the css, `float: justify` and `float:center` aren't valid properties. It's either right or left.